# Parsear un número bastante grande java

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente problema: quiero guardar el número 123456789123456789 en una base de datos, pero el valor almacenado no es exacto:

```
println params.randomQuantitative
println "Double: " + Double.parseDouble(params.randomQuantitative)
println "Float: " + Float.parseFloat(params.randomQuantitative)
println "Long: " + Long.valueOf(params.randomQuantitative)

Valor: 123456789123456789
Double: 1.23456789123456784E17
Float: 1.23456791E17
Long: 123456789123456789
```

En la BBDD me guarda 123456789123456784.

¿Hay alguna forma de que pueda guardar el mismo valor sin usar `long`?

Comment: Entonces tienes que modificar el tipo de la base de datos

Answer (score 3):

Veamos, quieres guardar el número `123456789123456789` y tenemos la siguiente situación:

1. Máximo valor de Integer: `2147483647`
2. Máximo valor de Long: `9223372036854775807`
3. Float y Double: No son la mejor opción a la hora de guardar números grandes en la base de datos debido a su manera de trabajar
4. Hay que tener en cuenta que el resultado depende mucho de cómo tengas definido el campo en la base de datos también...

Creo que la mejor solución es que en la base de datos lo almacenes como un **string**. Eso te evita todos los problemas de redondeo que te puedan dar al guardarlos como float/double y además te evitas problemas de longitudes máximas.

En cuanto a la manera de trabajar con un número almacenado en String en java, si no quieres usar el `Long` (con el método `Long.parseLong("numero")`, te recomiendo que uses [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), una clase cuyo límite es `(2 ^ 32) ^ Integer.MAX_VALUE`, y que además tiene un constructor que acepta un String como parámetro:
`BigInteger n = new BigInteger("num");`